# Should I use only pip in virtualenv?

Tags: pip, virtualenv

While in a virtual environment, what will happen if I use other methods of installation such as apt or manual install? Will the installation go into the virtual or global environment? I am asking this because some packages can't be installed using pip.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install` in the terminal installs by default to the global environment. `pip install` in my experience fails about half the time in both the global environment and the virtual environment, so I prefer to use pip in the virtual environment whenever possible, because it allows me to easily correct problems caused by `pip install` by manually deleting files that have been installed by `pip install` in the virtualenv virtual environment.

In Python, an *environment* is a folder (directory) which contains everything that a Python project/application needs in order to run in an organized, isolated fashion. When you delete the environment folder, you also delete everything that was installed by `pip` from that environment.

There's also `pip uninstall` but even so, it's safer to use `pip` in an isolated virtualenv virtual environment in your `/home` directory, because it puts the files installed by `pip` somewhere in the `/home` directory instead of in a directory that is owned by root.